# WP_Query: Mixing category__in and tag__in together

Tags: posts, categories, tags

I'm creating a "Related posts" section for my theme, based on a tutorial from [wpbeginner.com](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-related-posts-with-a-thumbnail-without-using-plugins/). It offered two options in selecting posts: those in the same category(ies), using `category__in`, or those with the same tag(s), using `tag__in`.

Is it possible to put of them into one big mixing pot, if you will, and select posts from all of them? I don't mean those that have the same category(ies) AND the same tag(s), but those that have either or.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. All [**Taxonomies**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) are stored in the db in the `wp_term_taxonomy` table. The following are all listed as taxonomies

- category
- post_tag
- link_category
- post_format and
- Custom taxonomies

All terms belonging to these taxonomies are stored in the `wp_terms` table. Tags are terms of the `post_tag` taxonomy, and all "categories" that you create in the post menu screen under "Categories" are actually terms of the taxonomy `category`

This makes it easy to combine the different taxonomies and terms in one query. To accomplish this, you are going to make use of the Taxonomy Parameters in [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to run a custom `tax_query`

OK, so first we need to get a list of all the categories and tags that belongs to a post. For categories you are going to use [`get_the_category`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) and for tags [`get_the_tags`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags). You are going to return that as an array which you are going to use in your custom query

```
global $post;
//get the categories a post belongs to          
$cats = get_the_category($post->ID);

$cat_array = array();
    foreach($cats as $key1 => $cat) {
        $cat_array[$key1] = $cat->slug;
    }

//get the categories a post belongs to      
$tags = get_the_tags($post->ID);

$tag_array = array();
    foreach($tags as $key2 => $tag) {
        $tag_array[$key2] = $tag->slug;
    }
```

Here is your custom query arguments. You can go and have look at the taxonomy parameters in the link to `WP_query` I've supplied. Also go and look at all the parameters that you can use in `WP_query` as some parameters from that tutorial have been depreciated a long time ago, for instance, like `caller_get_posts` which was replaced with `ignore_sticky_posts`

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $cat_array,
            'include_children' => false 
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $tag_array,
        )
    )
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

You can go play around with the code and modify as you wish.

Comment: Thank you. It works like an absolute dream. It will probably work better once I've styled everything, but that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Enjoy :-)

Comment: @Laxmana My pleasure. Glad my answer was useful to you as well :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
  $arrCats = array();
  $arrTags = array();

  if ($cats = get_the_category($post->ID)) foreach ($cats as $cat) $arrCats[] = $cat->term_id;
  if ($tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID)) foreach ($tags as $tag) $arrTags[] = $tag->term_id;

  $args = array(
    'numberposts'     => $num,
    'category__in'    => $arrCats,
    'tag__in'         => $arrTags,
    'post__not_in'    => array($post->ID),
    'orderby'         => 'post_date',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'post_type'       => $post->post_type,
    'post_status'     => 'publish'
  );   

  $posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to explain why and how this will solve the OP's problem, rather than posting only code.